# Android app using canvas in SurfaceView, pressing the recent apps button gives a laggy transition, how can this be changed?

Tags: java, android, canvas, tabs, surfaceview

As the title stated, whenever I press the recent tab button it glitches straight to the recent tab, whereas other apps I've used have a transition where it takes a "current state" image and resizes into the recent tab layout.

Is there a way to handle this? Or is it plainly some glitch in the code that is causing the lag?

I have overrided onPause() and onResume(), saving only 3 ints, so I don't understand why it could be lagging like that.

Comment: please try something first, and then post a question.

Comment: I have tried looking, can't find anything about it, hence the question